# ADF with Primefaces

Tags: primefaces, oracle-adf

I've added Primefaces 6.0 to an ADF Project, I could use the taglibrary 
I face  couple issues, 
1-  af:form  &  h:form  are not the same (af:form cant surround p:menu)
2- primefaces components are appearing without the style or themes
any support regarding these issues.

I used Jdev 12C Release 2.

Comment: Why would you combine ADF Faces with PrimeFaces, ADF Faces changes a lot of JSF Lifecycle, so you better off using only Primefaces for the front end and no af:tags, especially with 12c when you can use JSF2.

Comment: Mr. @AmrGawish thanks for your reply, I need to make use of some components from PF specially menus  & that has no equivalent in ADF faces; AFAIK.

Comment: I said you are better off not using ADF Faces components at all, and use only PF.